# Please help me to find the needed element in my css

Tags: php, html, css

I have some text on my website whose visibility is not very good and i want to change it's text color or background color, but i am not able to find it in my css file.

[image: Screenshot]

the part which is highlighted in red is one whose color i want to change.
you can see it yourself at AnHits.com
just Login with this demo account - username - demo  password - demo
and hover the mouse over Earn Coins on top right.
here is my main css file - http://www.anhits.com/css/style.css

here is the source code part which shows that test on my website -

```
    <div class="cont soft-blue fixed">
         <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu-wrap">
               <ul id="main_menu">
                  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog/index.php">Blog</a></li> 
               </ul>
                  <li>
                     <a href="index.php">Earn Coins</a>
                      <ul>              
    <li><a href="surf.php" target="_blank">Traffic Exchange</a></li>
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If Praveen's answer below doesn't work, you'll need to post more code or a link to the page where you took your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inspect Element option which lies in Chrome's Inspector and Also in Mozilla Firefox's Firebug Inspector. To get related styles and where they lie in your CSS.

And for now @Kolink and also @PraveenKumar has answered. You may refer to it if you just want support for this situation.

Comment: inspect element worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.cont.soft-blue.fixed .menu .menu-wrap #main_menu li ul {background: #fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main_menu>li>ul>li>a {
    color:white;
    background:black;
}
```

Experiment with values, but that's the selector you need.

Note that you could make your CSS a ***LOT*** more efficient (yes, with three levels of emphasis) by using the `>` combinator to limit the amount of searching the browser has to do.